# Enlarge Image View When Clicked in Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am using Picasso for a while now and I'm very satisfied with it. However I'm in need of enlarging an imageview's image which is loaded by Picasso from firebase. The codes below is in an adapter.java which is called inside the MainActivity.java

```
UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(fromUserID);
        UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String senderName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String userid = fromUserID;
                if (snapshot.hasChild("avata")){
                 final String receiverImage = snapshot.child("avata").getValue().toString();

                        if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId)) {
                            messageViewholder.senderMessageName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            messageViewholder.senderImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            if (fromMessageType.equals("text")) {
                                messageViewholder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                messageViewholder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
                            }else if (fromMessageType.equals("image")) {
                                messageViewholder.senderMessageImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Picasso.get().load(messages.getMessage()).into(messageViewholder.senderMessageImage);

                            }
```

Here is the xml

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/receiver_message_image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/receiver_image"
        android:layout_below="@id/receiver_message_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **ScaleGestureDetector** that will allow you to detect a particular gesture event that has occurred. It can also allow you to Zoom in and Zoom out depending on the gesture. In this example, I am using **[viewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)** to map the XML layout to the Java.

**XML Layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/symatech_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
   public class EnlargeImageViewWhenClicked extends AppCompatActivity {

    EnlargeImageViewBinding enlargeImageViewBinding;
    ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    float factor = 1.5f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        enlargeImageViewBinding = EnlargeImageViewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(enlargeImageViewBinding.getRoot()); // Setting up the view

        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new Listerner()); // Creating the ScaleGestureDetector object.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private class Listerner extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
            factor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor(); // The scaling factor from the previous scale event being applied to the current event.
            factor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(factor, 5.0f));
            enlargeImageViewBinding.imageView.setScaleY(factor);
            enlargeImageViewBinding.imageView.setScaleX(factor);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Before I Zoom In**
[image]

**After I Zoom In**
[image]

I sure hope this helps!

Comment: Its not working. I am working in an adapter using a recyclerView so I am not sure how to implement your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider subjecting your ImageView(messageViewholder.senderMessageImage) to the onScale function in the ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener  as on the example I gave. Something like this *(you might need to edit the code to fit your case. Also don't forget to get the rest of the **code** i.e initializing the **ScaleGestureDetector** and overriding the **onTouchEvent** function)*

```
 private class Listerner extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
            factor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor(); // The scaling factor from the previous scale event being applied to the current event.
            factor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(factor, 5.0f));
            **messageViewholder.senderMessageImage**.setScaleY(factor);
            **messageViewholder.senderMessageImage**.setScaleX(factor);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it didnt work. Looks like i need to reference `messageViewHolder.senderMessageImage` somewhere but dont know where.  I tried referencing it just before the `@Override` and in the `onCreate` but it didnt work

Comment: The adapter I created the above code doesnt have `onCreate` method so I wrote your solution in the caller activity